# How does the sentence 'Who did Tom say saw him?' work?

Tags: sentence-structure, questions, syntax, parsing, wh-questions

I understand the meaning but not the sentence formation/syntax. In my mother tongue this would make no sense. I would rather say:

> Who according to Tom saw him?

Perhaps the following will help to understand my problem

In normal question, we use this pattern: [question word] + auxiliary verb + subject + verb. For example:

- Did Kate eat the cake? (Potential answer: yes/no)
- Where did Kate eat the cake? (Potential answer: in the kitchen)

We also have questions that ask about the doer/agent of the activity. Pattern: question word + verb

- Who ate the cake? (Potential answer: Kate)

In my sentence:

- Who did Tom say saw him? (Potential answer: Kate)

The beginning of the question looks like a pattern for a normal question. However, we are asking about the doer/agent of the activity.

Comment: People don't ask "Who did Tom say" as a standalone question. It comes after the mention of who he saw. By itself, the question *is* confusing. In context, it comes together.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I disagree - it's a perfectly natural question from my perspective. Who did Tom say {saw him / he saw / was responsible for the accident / he was buying a present for} ? It's a pretty common way to ask about who Tom said something about.

Comment: What @ColleenV said. If prior context has clearly established that *some unknown person* is the current "topic", just *"Who did Tom say?"* is perfectly acceptable all on its own to ask who Tom suggested for the identity. But if the "unknown person" is *specifically* "someone who saw Tom*, and Tom himself has an opinion about who it might be, *"Who did Tom say [it was that] **saw him**?"* is fine.

Comment: @ColleenV I would pedantically start two of your examples with Whom: Who did Tom say saw him? Whom did Tom say he saw? Who did Tom say was responsible for the accident? Whom did Tom say he was buying a present for? (Or, For whom did Tom say he was buying a present?)

Comment: Tom said Kate saw him [Tom or someone else?]. I don't understand the problem. The issue is: Is "him" Tom? Or is "him" a third party?

Comment: We're not directly asking about the doer/agent of the "saw him" activity, we're asking about what Tom *said* - we're basically inquiring about the name of the person that Tom mentioned. The "who" here is less "who saw him", and more "Hey, remind me again, who was the person that Tom referred to earlier?" And then the "saw him" part is just to offer more detail on what Tom was talking about.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit difficult. I'll describe it in terms of Transformational Grammar: other grammars are available.

We start with

> Who<sub>1</sub> saw Tom<sub>2</sub>?

Then we embed that in a matrix "Tom said":

> Tom<sub>2</sub> said who<sub>1</sub> saw him<sub>2</sub>.

*Who* is now doing heavy work: equivalent to something like *the person<sub>1</sub> was, who<sub>1</sub>*.

Then this "fused relative", *who* is extracted from *Tom said who saw him*, leaving a trace:

> Who<sub>1</sub> did Tom<sub>2</sub> say *t*<sub>1</sub> saw him<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain it in a way that refers more to grammatical rules?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Imagine me asking the question 'How do you ask about the past in English?' My guess is that you wouldn't start by talking about 'matrix and fused relative'. You would explain by referring to grammatical rules. For example: Use one of the ways of talking about the past. Past Simple is the most universal one. Use did, then put the doer/agent of the action and then the verb in its basic form - e.g. Did he win? Take a look at what English learning books look like. The way it is explained is quite different from that in this answer.

Comment: Some learners have a more advanced knowledge of grammar and actually want a more profound analysis. Your command of English appears to be impressive, in fact the question you posed is more challenging for instance than a question comparing the simple present or the simple past.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Wow, I'll take the second sentence as a compliment. Nevertheless, I'm looking for an explanation that can be shown to learners rather than linguists.

Comment: @kyadere based on the analysis of this answer, you can extract the rule of WH-movement, I suppose. From the sentence "Tom said who saw him" it goes to relative phrase "Who [Tom said] saw him" to change the "who saw him" into subject, then change that into a question using simple past auxiliary "did" to get "Who did Tom say saw him", just like "I told them where to go" becomes "Where did I tell them to go" (this example uses bitransitive, easier to see the movement due to the object "them")

Comment: "Who" is not a fused relative here, it is an interrogative pronoun (since this is a question). Fused relatives with "who" are not common; see https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4665 In "Tom2 said who1 saw him2", "who" is an interrogative in an indirect question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to come at it without using any grammatical language at all, to see if it's possible for clarity to *emerge*. Just as an experiment.

> Did Tom say who saw him?
>
> -- Yes. Tom did say who saw him.
>
> Please tell me who saw Tom. Who did Tom say saw him?

NOTE: We are not asking, in that final question, merely about  the identity of the person who saw Tom. We are asking who it was that *Tom identified* as the person who saw him.

> Who did Tom say it was?
>
> --It was Kate who saw Tom.

It?

Answer (score 1):

In English questions are usually formed by starting with a declarative sentence, replacing the unknown part with a questions word (who, what, where, how) and moving the question word to the front.  So a sentence like

> Tom hugged Bill.

becomes

> Tom hugged whom?

which is a perfectly fine question. (It’s “whom” because Bill is the object of the verb.)

The problem is that you just can’t move whom to the front.  If you did you would get

> Whom Tom hugged? (*)

which is not a proper english sentence. I’m not sure why. (I’ll put a (*) next to phrases that aren’t something you should say.) But there is a work around.   Instead of “Tom hugged Bill” you can say

> Tom did hug Bill.

(Which is correct English, though not the usual way to say this.) Now we get

> Tom did hug whom?  (*)

(In contrast to “Tom hugged who?”, this is something no anglophone would say; it’s just a step on the path to the next one.) Now the “Whom” moves to the front and drags the did along with it.

> Whom did Tom hug?

The auxiliary verb “did” moving to the front is important.  An auxiliary verb moving to the front and leaving its The main verb behind really marks this as a question.

—-

In your sentence it’s the same thing but more complicated because there are two verbs in the original sentence.  Start with

> Tom said that Bill saw him.

Simplify to

> Tom said Bill saw him.

Replace Bill with who.

> Tom said who saw him?

(I think it’s “who” not “whom” because Bill is the subject of saw and not the object of said, but I could be wrong.) It’s not very clear that this is a question, so we want to move “who” to the front.  But again that leads to something an anglophone wouldn’t think is right. So, rephrase with “did”

> Tom did say who saw him?  (*)

Move the who to the front dragging the did with it.

> Who did Tom say saw him?

—-

The same idea works for present tense.

> You eat what?

becomes

> What do you eat?

—-

> Did Kate eat the cake?

is the same idea but without the question word.  We start with the declarative sentence

> Kate ate the cake.

There is no single part of this that we are uncertain about, but rather whether the whole event happened.  So again add the did.

> Kate did eat the cake.

Now the did moves to the front to make a question

> Did Kate eat the cake?

—-

Other auxiliary verbs can follow this pattern. E.g.

> You have eaten.

Becomes

> Have you eaten?

And

> Bob has met Chris?

could become

> Has Bob met Chris?

or

> Whom has Bob met?

or

> Who has met Chris?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide more examples of this type of question:

> What did Tom say battled him?

> Where did Tom say he met him?

The concept of a "fused relative" Colin's answer mentions isn't as difficult as it sounds. You can consider these questions as if there are extra words implied here:

> Who did Tom say [the person that] saw him [was]?

> What did Tom say [the thing that] battled him [was]?

> Where did Tom say [the place that] he met him [was]?

As TimR's answer demonstrates, the part "the __ that ___" is a relative clause, so it can be replaced by "it" in context.

The reason it's called a "fused relative" is that this relative clause is *fused* into the question word.

Fused relatives actually can be in sentences, too:

> What he battled was a terrible cancer.

> Where he went was previously uncharted.

The fused relative sentences can also be expanded into normal relative clauses:

> *The thing that* he battled was a terrible cancer.

> *The place that* he went was previously uncharted.

As before, you know these are normal relative clauses now because you can replace them with "it" as well:

> *It* was a terrible cancer.

> *It* was previously uncharted.

Hope this helps explain the concept!

Comment: "Who" isn't a fused relative here, it is an interrogative pronoun, since this is a question. Fused relatives with "who" are not common; see https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4665

Comment: @sumelic Does the answer still work despite the incorrect language or should I delete it entirely?

Comment: Well, I think the answer works as an explanation of a fused relative so unfortunately, I'm not sure it's all that applicable here. It's correct that a fused relative can be rephrased to something like "the person that", "the thing that", "The place that". Distinguishing between fused relatives and interrogatives can be difficult; here is a question I found on that: [Is 'who' here a relative word or an interrogative pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443384/)

Comment: I'd hate to see the effort composing this answer go to waste so my suggestion I think would be an edit to clarify that the fused relative construction may not be involved in the original poster's sentence ("Who according to Tom saw him?").